# How shall I get smooth servo output from pixhawk?

Tags: quadcopters

I am getting improper servor output. A slight increase in throttle suddenly increases servo output of the pixhawk.
[This is the link to my servo output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DEaC1lv7hFuIM0Nxsgxw68OHV6b-dIPD/view)

As this can be seen I get sudden jump from 1000 to 1800 on slight movement in the throttle which is unsafe.
When I used receiver (means without pixhawk), directly plugging esc into channel 3 of the receiver, it works completely fine. And servo master also shows proper result.

[This is the link to my pixhawk 2.4.8 params](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/uploads/short-url/7Q4aT4wTGSvLX0teI74D0HqW4lG.param)

Thanking you

Comment: I'm not well versed in pizhawk, but is this iterm windup? Move the aircraft/flight controller around and see if the outputs change. If so, it's just the flight controller trying to level/control a machine that isn't responding

Comment: @BrydonGibson you did not understand my question.Pixhawk is a flight controller that sends servo output to esc to control the motors. But my flight controller on slight increase in the throttle suddenly sends pwm signal to esc from (1000 to 1800). That is too much of thrust to handle.I want pwm signal from pixhawk to esc be smooth .

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The flight controller is trying to stabilize the craft on top of just mixing the signals. It will change the outputs not only based on your control but based on whether the craft is level. The phenomena for this to change on the bench is called iterm windup